# C++ 2D dynamic array allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I have a `float**` array that contains `num_rows` rows and `num_cols` columns. I'd like to determine the number of occurrences of every number between 0-9 columnwise. To do this, I thought of using another 2D array of size `[10][num_cols]`, so that for each column the number corresponding to an element is the number of occurrences of that number in the original table.
Example: if the original table contains `1 2 3 1 1` in the fifth column, then in the second column, the values should be like: `1-> 3, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1`.

I tried using the function as follows, but it gives me a pointer error. I tried using vectors but that too brings no luck.

```
int ** attribute_count(float * * input, int row_num, int col_num) {
    int ** arr_2 = new int * [10];
    int * arr = new int[10 * col_num];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++) {
            arr_2[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++) {
            int temp = input[i][j];
            arr_2[temp][j]++;
        }
    }
    return arr_2;
}
```

EDIT:
I tried your suggestions. The new code is:

```
    int** attribute_count(float** input, int row_num, int col_num) {
    int** arr_2 = new int* [10];
    int* arr = new int[10 * col_num];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++) {
            arr_2[i] = new int[col_num];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++) {
            int temp = input[i][j];
            arr_2[temp][j]++;
        }
    }
    return arr_2;
}
```

This still gives me memory errors. The function is being called in the .cpp like this:

```
int** attr = attribute_count(training_data, 10, num_cols_train);
    cout<<attr[5][1];
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong even now?

Comment: What is the exact statement of the "pointer error"?
You are not allocating memory to each index in 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

arr_2 is defined and allocated as an array of pointers to int, but you don't actually assign/allocate those pointers.

Here's a stab at correcting your code - however I'm not convinced you have rows and columns the right way around...

```
int ** attribute_count(float ** input, int row_num, int col_num)
{
int ** arr_2 = new int * [10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr_2[i] = new int[col_num];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < col_num ; j++)
        {
            arr_2[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row_num; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++)
        {
            int temp = input[i][j];
            arr_2[temp][j]++;
        }
    }
    return arr_2;
}
```

Comment: Tried, still troubling. Please see the edit I made in the main question.

Comment: Your change is not for the better. You now both allocate, and loop, too much.

Comment: Can you write the correct code for this? I am new to this kind of programming and would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You've only allocated one dimension of `arr_2`.  You need to loop through and allocate an array of ints on each one to get the 2nd dimension.

EDIT: Also, what's up with `arr`?  You allocate it, never use it, don't return it, and don't deallocate it.  That's how we spell memory leak.

Comment: Tried, still troubling. Please see the edit I made in the main question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in incorrect allocation of the 2D array. Try

```
int ** arr_2 = new int* [row_num];
for (int i = 0; i < row_num; i++)
    arr_2[i] = new int[col_num];
```

Comment: <code>int** attribute_count(float** input, int row_num, int col_num) {
    int** arr_2 = new int* [10];
    int* arr = new int[10 * col_num];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++) {
            arr_2[i] = new int[col_num];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_num; j++) {
            int temp = input[i][j];
            arr_2[temp][j]++;
        }
    }
    return arr_2;
}

Comment: Tried, still troubling. Please see the edit I made in the main question.

Comment: @Nathan822 Your indexing is very confusing. `row_num` is usually used to represent the number of rows, and `col_num` is used to represent the number of columns. While in your code you use `10` for columns number and `col_num` for rows. Also, the `arr` variable seems to be unused.

Comment: I am using 10 for row_num, since I want to keep track of the 10 numbers.

Comment: @Nathan822 What do you mean 'keep track of the 10 numbers'? In your code you create 2D array `arr_2` with `10` columns and `col_num` rows. Also, you create 1D array named `arr` with `10 * col_num` cells. Note, you don't use `arr` in your function. What is it's purpose?